# How do I use javascript to crawl a directory tree for a search and output a URL as a link and reset the search for a second run

Tags: javascript, html, search, web-crawler

I am using plain javascript. I have 45 html web pages (in 17 sub-directories) to teach introduction to psychology and I have created a search routine in javascript so my students can search the web pages for a specific text. If that text is found, then I want to display the webpage that has the text as a link so they can click on it and be taken to that page. The search routine is currently only running through one specific webpage to find the text.  I think I can create an array of all 45 web pages, but I'm hoping there is a better way to crawl a directory tree using javascript. The main directory is called "pages" and has 17 sub-directories by psychology topic.

1. Is there a way to crawl the directory tree without having to create a massive array?
2. How do I display the webpages that contain the search word as a link?
3. I have noticed that occasionally the access to the file does not work? Should there be a timeout and let the routine try again?
4. I have also noticed that the search menu option - which opens the div for searching -once it is run - does not clear the page if the student clicks the search menu option the second time. How do I reset the DIV to run the routine a second time?

Thanks for any help!

This is my code for the search routine if that helps...

```
    <div id="Searchdiv" class="white-text" style="border: 2px solid white;">this is the acquire a word division
    <div style="color:white; margin: auto; width: 50%;"> <label for="name">
          <span>Term to seach for: </span> </label>
        <form><input style="float:right;" id="sText" name="sText" placeholder="What word do you want to find.."
            value="goofy" type="text"></form>
        <button style="color:black;" onclick="loadXMLDoc(document.getElementById('sText').value)">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>


     <script>
        function loadXMLDoc(Sword) {
             urlConstruct = "https://www.blahblahblah/pages/blahblahblah.html"
             var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             const Wpage = this.responseText;
             let regx = new RegExp(Sword,"i")  
             const content = Wpage.textContent;
             const hasText = regx.test(Wpage); 
             // see if it worked
            document.getElementById("searchdiv").innerHTML = Sword + " HELLO! got to step 3 and hasText is " + hasText;
                }
              };
        xhttp.open("GET", urlConstruct, true);
       xhttp.send();
         }
    </script>
```

Comment: You should not crawl your entire HTML documents for each search. Instead you should be creating a search index up-front, which you then query with Ajax. This search index could be a huge array you store in some file - but there are a lot of better solutions. Of course having a dedicated search solution creates additional overhead, but it's much better than anything you can write from scratch. For example https://www.elastic.co/ is probably overkill for such a small site, but in my opinion best suited as a website search index.

Comment: I read that plain javascript can't crawl, so figured a "global" index would work (save time as it is not created over and over) and concatenation of each "positive" search to the innerHTML output with some additional tags to make the output an <a href>.    
  I do not have any idea how long it will take to go through all the pages, so I might add a progress bar in the output field to let the students know something is happening.